# Localize a MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, master-pages

I have a MasterPage and some controls in it, I also have a dropdown with languages, I'd like to know if theres is way to localize all of the controls within the masterpage because it doesn't have the InitializeCulture method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the Culture in the global.asax file to ensure that all requests have it from the lowest level.

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-NZ");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

All controls should pick this up through the application.

Comment: No such thing as global.asx its global.asax

Comment: Try hitting the edit button next time instead of pointing out typos on the internet.

Comment: I did, it said `Edit has to be atleast 6 characters` and there is nothing wrong with answer except just that one character. so just put it in the comments.